# Finding integer solutions to $2x^2+y^2+8x+2y-93=0$

Tags: polynomials, integers

> Given integers $x$ and $y$, find all sets of $(x, y)$ that satisfy the following:
> $$2x^2+y^2+8x+2y-93=0$$

Factorization was the first thought I have, however, after rearranging as follows:

$$(2x+\text{ ___ }y+\text{ ___ })(x+\text{ ___ }y+\text{ ___ })$$

I find it difficult to find values for the coefficients of $y$, because we'll always get $xy$ terms.

Note: due to the fact that $x$ and $y$ are both integers, I suppose the coefficients should also be integers?

Comment: make perfect square in $x$ and $y$

Comment: $2(x+2)^2 + (y+1)^2 =102$

Comment: You won't be able to factor the polynomial. Follow @mathophile's hint.

Comment: @mathophile should the next step be substituting numbers in? Or is there a better method?

Comment: Note that $(y+1)^2=102-2(x+2)^2\geqslant 0\implies -9\leqslant x\leqslant 5$. Also, one can show that $x$ has to be odd.